# How to add my own created certificate authority to system trusted repositories

Tags: centos, security, ssl, certificates

I was told that I can add my created CA to trusted repositories/authorities in my system instead of adding it from browser and configuring in in `ssl.conf`.

Yet I can't find anything similar on the web. Is that possible?

I'm working on CentOS server .

Comment: You need to specify which distribution you want to do this on. e.g., on Arch, the CAs are in subdirs in /usr/share/ca-certificates/ (probably the same place they'd be on Debian as that's where the CAs come from apparently).

Comment: @MelBoyce I did . I wonder why there's a lack of OpenSSL References on the web !! no body is answering my question , can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the PEM file with your root certificate to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
- Run `sudo update-ca-trust`